# How to check included files in Makefile? (Linux)

Tags: linux, makefile

My Makefile has a setup that looks like this. The problem here is that. When I use a build mode of SM5600, xqwskeysenderadapter.o is still being checked when I try to "Make" it. How can I know the files that were successfully included when I used "Make" on my application?

```
TEMPLATE = app
USE_QT  = y
#USE_DB  = y
USE_DEV = y
#USE_QT_MODULES=y
USE_QTBASE=y
USE_LCDBASE=y

USE_PROGRAM_UTILITY = n

include $(TWS_BUILDER_HOME)/TOPDIR.init

TARGET = desktopmanager

POFILES = desktopmanager.po

OBJS += main.o
OBJS += desktopwidget.o
OBJS += calibrate.o
OBJS += calwidget.o 
OBJS += simeq.o

MOCOBJS += moc_desktopwidget.o
MOCOBJS += moc_calwidget.o

EXTRA_LIBS += -lm


ifeq ($(MODE), SM5500)
BUILD_MODE = SM
else
ifeq ($(MODE), SM5600)
BUILD_MODE = SM
else
ifeq ($(MODE), SM5500V2)
BUILD_MODE = SM
else
BUILD_MODE = DELIOUS
endif
endif
endif

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE), DELIOUS)
EXTRA_CXXFLAGS += -DDELIOUS_BUILD
OBJS += xvirtualkeyboard.o
OBJS += xqwskeysenderadapter.o
OBJS += xconsolekeysenderadapter.o
MOCOBJS += moc_xvirtualkeyboard.o
endif

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE), SM)
EXTRA_CXXFLAGS += -DSM_BUILD
PRESUBDIRS += XServerWidget
PRESUBDIRS += XWidgetProperty
EXTRA_LIBS += -lXServerWidget
EXTRA_LIBS += -lXWidgetProperty
endif



DEPLOY_BIN_FILES += desktopmanager
RUN_FILE += desktopmanager

include $(TOPDIR)/Rules.mk
```

Is there something wrong in my code to include or exclude files?

EDIT: This is the entire makefile I am using.

Comment: Is `xqws.o` the only thing that is set wrong? What `-D*_BUILD` flag is used in that build? Is `xvirtualkeyboard.o` also included in `OBJS`?

Comment: Sorry Etan, I posted a different Makefile earlier. Please base your comment again to my updated Makefile. Thanks.

Comment: How are you selecting the build mode?

Comment: On my case I only type ". builld SM5600" then when I "echo $mode" it says "SM5600". When I type ". build SM5500" then when I "echo $mode" it says "SM5500". Sorry I am really new to linux.

Comment: The shell variable `$mode` is not the same as the make variable `MODE` unless something sets one from the other somewhere. How do you run the build after that command or does that command run the build?

Comment: I think something sets `$mode` somewhere to run the build. `. build SM5600` or `. build SM5500` only sets the mode. I have to type `build SM5600` for SM5600 or `build SM5500` for SM5500 then it will compile the whole directory which is around 9GB in size.

Comment: If there is a `build` script in the current directory and a `build` command in the `$PATH` that do different things that is *very* confusing and odd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71163/discussion-between-john-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about just check the .o files in the output directory?

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?